# Connecting Databricks community edition to Neo4j and getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neo4j' error

Tags: pyspark, neo4j, databricks, modulenotfounderror, databricks-community-edition

I'm practicing with Databricks community edition and trying to read/write a dataframe to Neo4j and following the guide [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-neo4j-with-pyspark-on-databricks-eb3d127f2245). I did install the Neo4j package via Maven as you see here:

[image]

But the issue is that it doesn't recognize the `neo4j` module.

[image]

Do you know by any chance how to get it working? does Neo4j work with community edition of databricks or a VM instance is required to work with it?